# Помогите добавить платформы

Tags: python

Создавая игру захотелось добавить в неё платформы или блоки по которым игрок мог бы передвигаться
Напишите пожалуйста код для добавления платформ и взаимодействия с ними.
Мой код

```
from idlelib import window

import pygame

from turtle import width as t_width


pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 500))


pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('right_3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('right_6.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('left_1.png'), pygame.image.load('left_2.png'), pygame.image.load('left_3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('left_4.png'), pygame.image.load('left_5.png'), pygame.image.load('left_6.png')]

JumpRight = [pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_1.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_4.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_5.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_7.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_8.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_9.png')]

JumpLeft = [pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_1.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_4.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_5.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_7.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_8.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_9.png')]


bg = pygame.image.load('bg2.png')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('ninja.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 249
width = 48
height = 66
speed = 8


isJump = False
JumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
animCount = 0



def drawWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 30:
        animCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))


    pygame.display.update()



        





run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 249 and x > 380 and x < 410:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450 - width - 5 and x > 380 and x < 410  :
        y += speed

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 10:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1200 - width - 10:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        animCount = 0





    if not(isJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            if JumpCount < 0:
                y += (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            JumpCount = 10




    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False



    drawWindow()
```

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки и возникшие проблемы.

Comment: вроде тут ответ есть https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Mb9RJktnXO8&list=PLjRuaCofWO0O8qv2or33DGHpQ6kN_CATM&index=5&t=0s

Comment: Там ответа не нашёл (

Answer (score 0):

Это не твой код, а код с ютуба. для начала попробуй сам, когда не выйдет, задавай вопрос, показывая в каком участке не получилось.
https://realpython.com/pygame-a-primer/#pygame-concepts
вот тебе пища для размышлений и английский потренируешь